# Get SSIS package name with C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I'm copying SSIS packages from one SQL server to another in a C# program via DTUTIL. The packages are in MSDB.

```
string dtutilCmd = "/c DTUTIL /SOURCESERVER " + sourceServer + " /SQL " + myPackage + " /DestServer " + destServer + " /COPY " + myPackage;

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
startInfo.Arguments = dtutilCmd;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

The variables in the `dtutilCmd` string are all strings. The issue is when my users input the package name they can get the case wrong. They might write `MYPACKAGE` so it gets deployed as `MYPACKAGE`, even if it actually exists as `MyPackage` on the source server, which I want to preserve.

So I want to somehow grab the package name, and feed it into the last part of my `dtutilCmd` string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is make use of 'Application' class of Microsoft.Dts.Runtime namespace. You then establish a connection using that and get the packages info from the MSDB.

Here is link that gives more details on how to go about doing it programatically - [Enumerating Available Packages Programmatically](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/run-manage-packages-programmatically/enumerating-available-packages-programmatically)

Comment: Got this to work. For people in the future, the code there will not work outright, it needs quite a bit of tweaking, but the solution is legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

Extract your Integration Service Catalog to ispac. Open it with SSDT, and deploy to your new server. Much easier.

Comment: Why do i get a minus for this? there is no point of copying ssis packages between servers using DTUTIL...

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I also don't know what your solution means. Copying packages between servers with DTUTIL is the only way I know how to do it through a C# program. My program does a lot of stuff, so deploying an SSIS package absolutely needs to be done 100% within the C# program. No opening SSMS or anything on the side.